# In Python, getting each element of a variable-length list into a function call?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have a function f(*args). The user inputs a bunch of words separated by commas, I split this into a list using .split(','). I want to be able to call a function f(word1, word2, ..., wordn) where there are n words in the list. How can I do this?

Note that I would like to just define f instead as f(list) and just input the list, but the instructor requires that we use f(*args).

Example: The user inputs 'hi, church, banana', I split into the list ['hi', 'church', 'banana'] and I want to call f('hi', 'church', 'banana'). I don't know how to do the last step since the user can input any amount of words.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your problem? In knowing what to pass instead of a `list` or in parsing the `*args` within your function definition?

Comment: @xnx I want to be able to call f(word1, word2, ..., wordn) given a list with those values in them, no matter what length the list is. I have no idea how to do that since I can't just do f(list[0], list[1], list[2]) since the list can be any length. That's it.

Comment: you won't be able to call it like you want to, precisely because you don't know how many arguments you will have. Have a read as to what the `*` operator actually does, and you will realise you can use it anywhere - not just when you are unpacking arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
  def f(*words):
      for word in words:
          print word

  line = "This is a line of text with multiple words"
  words = line.split()

  f(*words)
```

Note the use of * in the call unpacks the list into a tuple which is effectively the same as calling with multiple argument

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function with `def f(*args):` all of the arguments passed to the function appear in the sequence `args` which you can iterate over:

```
def f(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print arg

f('Foo', 'Bar', 'Spam')

Foo
Bar
Spam
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking in the slightest. I know what args does.

Comment: In your earlier comment you explicitly stated that you wanted to be able to call `to be able to call f(word1, word2, ..., wordn)`.

Comment: Yes. But you don't understand the rest of my question. I obviously already understand how to do f(word1, word2, word3), but I wanted to be able to call f(word1, word2, ..., wordn) regardless of how many words is. Thus, f(*list) fits the bill here as Tony Suffolk says above.